# creating a List type Field/attribute in django model

Tags: django, django-models

What I'm trying to do

```
class Node(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Ancestor = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Descendent = models.
```

In the Descendent attribute I want to assgin a list of objects of Node.

What can I Do?

Comment: You can use `ManyToManyField` referencing to itself

Answer (score 0):

You can have a foreign key to the Node itself. It's not common to save arrays in the database, so each element of the array will have its own row in the database table.

```
class Node(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Ancestor = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Descendent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Comment: If you didn't get the database part, just let me know.

Comment: I didn't get the database .Beside My descendent list is not all of the database row,just some row.